# No response code return when requesting a site and the program keeps running

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When I try to print response code when I request [this site](https://www.carrefouruae.com) using `requests.get` in python
no response code is showing and the program keeps running

This is my code:

```
import requests
print ("start")
response = requests.get("https://www.carrefouruae.com/")
print(response)
print("done")
```

Any explanation why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify `User-Agent` HTTP header when doing the request:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}

response = requests.get("https://www.carrefouruae.com/", headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Prints:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html dir="LTR" lang="en-AE"><head>

...
```